# Get attribute count

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, category-attribute

I'm using bellow code for displaying the amount of product/s in specific category on my home page:

```
<?php 
                    $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4)
                    ->getProductCount();
                    echo($products_count);
                    ?>
```

Where 4 is the number/ID of my specific category.

Now I would like to display the amount of attributes with name "lp_brand" from this specific category.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    //->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('lp_brand', array('eq' => 47));
echo $products->getSize();
```

Comment: I tried the above code and it is displaying a total number of products from category no 4.

What if i know the id of lp_brand which in this case is "47".

Comment: @haver15 I have edited my code. Try again.

Comment: I just tried the code, and it is returning 0 results. But for this case I know there should be "1" particular product in this category wehere lp_brand id is 47.

Comment: My bed, above code @MagePsycho is correct. Thank you very much. :)